# Updating Access Query Criteria using QueryDef

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am attempting to drill down data by updating the Query Criteria before opening another Form. The only way to do this is to recreate the SQL string and update the Query via QueryDef.

I have transcribed the SQL I need from a Query with a hard coded Criteria so that I can be confident that the Datasheet returned is what I require.

[MsgBox strSQL shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhI2l.png)

I get a Syntax Error (missing operative) in Query Expression.

[VBA used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMDOG.png)

I wonder if it is something to do with it being a two table join, the second table (CD-KEY) isn't used in the form.

I have tried a simple QueryDef update with one table and it works fine.

Comment: I would help very much if you would show your code as text, not as image. That said: I'm almost sure your parenthesis don't match.

Comment: _The only way to do this is to recreate the SQL string_ ... No, you can apply a filter.

Comment: Thanks to you both, but FunThomas has cracked it. I have removed one '(' and it has solved my problem. I have looked at this for days.